# MissingFieldException when using Moles for class with const members

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moles

We are using Moles to isolate new units from legacy mechanisms we cannot modify.
When such legacy classes contain const members, we are getting a long series of MissingFieldException for each of the const members.

What causes it?
How can I skip these during debug sessions? (I'm getting it even when clearing all exception
types "breaks")

Comment: you mean "thrown" ? you unchecked all the checkboxes and still get exceptions while debugging?

Comment: Indeed, if I'm checking all checkboxes, for each of the fields I'm getting once the original exception and then another "crossing managed/native boundaries" exception of the same type for the same field. If I'm unchecking them, I'm getting only the second type of exceptions.

Comment: pff weird stuff. hard to tell like this. is it hard to supply enough information so that I can reproduce it? (googling for it now but I guess you did your share without luck already...)

Comment: I have found how to skip the annoying exceptions "Tools->Options->Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native...". I would like to better understand the reason of the root cause.